# Typo3 C# interface (SOAP or REST)

Tags: c#, rest, soap, typo3

I've got the task to connect a platform based on .net via a plugin to Typo3. I'm not very familiar with Typo3, but with the .net stack (actually using C#).
The requirements include writing data to Typo3 and retrieving data from Typo3.

Looking at the Typo3 API documentation (http://api.typo3.org/), I don't find any information on the interfaces I could use, or even how to stuff data into the system. I used all my favorite search engines, but ended up here. (Or I just searched for the wrong terms?!)

Following requirements have been provided additionally:

- No writing/reading to/from the database (we don't get access to it for multiple reasons)
- Use of a general solution (which could be re-used for different entities)
- Synchronous process (so we get an error when inserting data has failed, etc.)
- No batch import/export solution
- Authentication must be used

What I search for is a simple interface which I can consume from my plugin. Something like SOAP, REST or any variant which I can call via http/https - including authentication.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: We now have a workaround by using a custom WebService which is specialized to write and read data to and from Typo3. But the question is still valid: Is there no direct solution? Anything like an usual SOAP or REST webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no external API built in TYPO3 out of the box.
Quick search for REST or SOAP based extensions (http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/) to provide e.g. page structure and contents from TYPO3 doesn't provide any results either.

The only solution is to write an own extension providing a SOAP or REST API to access TYPO3 data.